# Tkinter using python

Tags: tkinter

If i have a main window in tkinter, then I click a button and it opens another window (secondary window) and minimize the first one and then i decide to click on a button on this second window to go back to the first window (like a "return button") how can i do this option of returning to the first window by pressing the botton on the second window in tkinter? Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk

def funcion():
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    root.iconify()

def funcion2():
    vuelta_ventana.iconify()
    root.deiconify() 

root = tk.Tk()
boton = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir otra ventana", command=funcion)
boton2 = tk.Button(root, text="return", command=funcion2)
boton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty much the same, like you did with the first function "funcion".
However you have to pack the button calling funcion2 in your tk.Toplevel.

Grouping your Windows / Frames in classes will help you in the long run, once your app gets larger.

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("300x300")
        self.popup = None

        self.buton = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Abrir otra ventana",
            command=self.funcion
        )
        self.buton.pack()


    def funcion(self):
        self.iconify()
        if self.popup is None:
            self.popup = MyToplevel(self)
        else:
            self.popup.deiconify()


class MyToplevel(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master

        self.buton = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Return",
            command=self.funcion2
        )
        self.buton.pack()

    def funcion2(self):
        print("hello")
        self.master.deiconify()
        #self.destroy()#maybe more useful? 
        self.iconify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @caskuda 's answer, the directly corrected code of yours would be

```py
import tkinter as tk

def funcion():
    global otra_ventana
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    return_button=tk.Button(otra_ventana,text='Return',command=funcion2).pack()
    root.iconify()

def funcion2():
    otra_ventana.iconify()
    root.deiconify() 

root = tk.Tk()
boton = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir otra ventana", command=funcion)
boton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

And if your aim is to only switch windows, you could also try this approach

```py
import tkinter as tk

def switch(target,window):
    target.iconify()
    window.deiconify()

root=tk.Tk()
button=tk.Button(root,text="Abrir otra ventana",command=lambda:switch(root,otra_ventana)).pack()
otra_ventana=tk.Toplevel(root)
return_button=tk.Button(otra_ventana,text='Return',command=lambda:switch(otra_ventana,root)).pack()
otra_ventana.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Here I have initialized both the windows in the beginning and then used the `.withdraw()` method to hide/remove the second window from visibility. The use of `lambda` function lets us call the desired function along with the parameters when needed. The function `switch()` takes in 2 parameters, the former being the window to be iconified and the latter being the window to be deiconified.